# How can I tell if I value already exists in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Database entry]

I would like to receive a `bool` letting me know if my document has a `Wasiyyah` or not..

What I've tried:
`Firestore.firestore().collection(user!.uid).document(docID).value(forKey: "Wasiyyah")`

Which only crashes every time, so there must be something I'm not understanding here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any function to check if a field exists in a document. You'll have to fetch the document and check for it's existence:

```
let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection(user!.uid).document(docID)

docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let data = document.data()
        // Check if the field exists in data
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```